# Call Back Url With Url In A Query String Not Creating Request Token With TweetSharp

Tags: twitter, tweetsharp

I am trying to send a returnurl query string to the GetRequestToken, but I either get a "?" as the token response, or the "#" gets stripped out on the return callback.  When I do get a valid response back, the # and everything after it is stripped out on the returnurl.

```
var service = new TwitterService(Config.Twitter.ConsumerKey, Config.Twitter.ConsumerSecret);
var requestToken = service.GetRequestToken(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri));
var uri = service.GetAuthorizationUri(requestToken);
```

**HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)**

```
"https://localhost:44301/twitter/linkaccount?eventid=3762&returnurl=/directors#eventsettings?eventid=3762"
```

**Request.Url.AbsoluteUri**

```
"https://localhost:44301/twitter/linkaccount?eventid=3762&returnurl=%2fdirectors%23eventsettings%3feventid%3d3762"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like Twitter doesnt like the "#"  in the callback url.  So I split the left and right parts of it and added that as a query string, then combined them on the result back for the real redirect.

```
https://localhost:44301/twitter/linkaccount?eventid=3762&leftPart=/directors&rightPart=eventsettings?eventid=3762
```